# Как достать из enum число и присвоить его другой переменной?

Tags: c#

Как достать из enum число и присвоить это число другой переменной ? Учитывая что элемент enum будет выбираться программой рандомным образом

Comment: `int someVariable = (int)SomeEnum.SomeValue;`

Comment: @Yami а если заранее не известно какой элемент enum будет использоваться ? Допустим берется рандомный элемент enum и его число присваивается другому элементу, как достать рандомный элемент я разобрался ,но теперь не знаю как присвоить его число другой переменной

Comment: Возможно данный вариант Вам поможет:
 int x = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum), SomeName);

Comment: @handy Прошу прощения ,не совсем понял что имеется ввиду под SomeName

Comment: SomeName - имя именованной константы в SomeEnum. Подробнее можно здесь почитать: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Simon: Не важно какое из значений `Enum` вы будете использовать, просто результат кастуйте к типу `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сделайте приведение к типу `int`:

```
class Program
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        SomeValue,
        SomeValue2,
        SomeValue3,
        SomeValue4
    }

    static int getEnumValueAsInt(SomeEnum value)
    {
        return (int)value;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        SomeEnum[] arr = new[]
        {
            SomeEnum.SomeValue2, SomeEnum.SomeValue3,
            SomeEnum.SomeValue, SomeEnum.SomeValue4
        };
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randv = rand.Next(1,4);
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Current int value: {getEnumValueAsInt(arr[randv])}, Current enum: {arr[randv]}");
    }
}
```

Тест: [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/Wwi8EC)

Comment: Брррррррррррр...

Comment: @Qwertiy: What going on?

Comment: Зачем так издеваться над енумом?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Этот вопрос надо задать ТС =)

Comment: обычно в int кастят если в базу записывают.. а так не понятно зачем еще такое нужно :)

Comment: @SultanovShamil: Все вопросы к ТС

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас числа enum-ов идут по порядку, а так и есть если вы их вручную не пропишите. То для генерации случайного числа enum-ы вам вообще не нужны.

Допустим у вас есть

```
enum SomeEnum { a, b, c, d };
```

Мы знаем что всего 4 значения `[0,1,2,3]`, итого берём случайное.

```
Random ran = new Random();
int randomInt = ran.Next(4);
```

Если ваши enum-ы идут не по порядку, тогда используйте [Enum.GetNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.getnames(v=vs.110).aspx) для получения списка всех имён, и уже из этого списка выбирайте случайное значение.